# How to ignore unknown fields automatically in solr

Tags: solr

How can I ignore fields that aren't in the schema automatically with an updateProcessor?

I disabled the auto-field create with

`bin/solr config -c gettingstarted -p 8983 -action set-user-property -property update.autoCreateFields -value false`

When I go to index I get

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=0553573403] unknown field 'name'",
    "code":400}}
```

Which makes sense as the "name" field isn't in my schema. I simply want Solr to ignore it and move on with that it has found.

I'm not well versed with these processor chains but that was how people have suggested to use but I can't figure out how to make my Solr actually use the updateRequestProcessorChain automatically.

Here is my

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="ignoreunknown">
  <processor class="solr.IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Comment: what solr version are you using ?

Comment: @root545 Latest stable 7.x. (7.3).